# Get previous commands in Terminal that match the currently typed command

Tags: command-line, bash, shortcut-keys

In some terminals you can do something like this...

Type some command

```
nmap -sn 192.168.1.1/24
```

Then go on to do other things in the terminal for a while. Then later you can type

```
nmap
```

and then just press the <kbd>↑</kbd> key and it will index through all of the commands that started with what you typed, in this case `nmap` for example.

My example was pretty short but sometimes you type a very long command that you want to run again, and I know you can press <kbd>↑</kbd> until you find it again, but that goes through ***every*** command and could take a while if you typed it long ago.

Is there anyway to get this to work in Ubuntu's Terminal?

Comment: Are you aware of `!`? Just in case: you can always type `!nmap` and this will execute the first command in the history that matches `nmap`. If you remember enough part of the command it can be faster than manually searching with arrows. Moreover you can modify the command using substitutions `!nmap:s/something/something-else/`.  Although this doesn't request confirmation for execution of the command, so you'll see what is going to happen only when it's already started.

Comment: Use ctrl-r and type nmap

Comment: Just to mention, I switched from bash to [zsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) which supports this out of the box

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, there is a very simple way to search through your command history. When at the terminal, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> to begin a search, then you can type `nmap` and it will search back to the last command using nmap.

If you don't want the last command that contained the 'nmap' word but some other further to the past, then you can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> again as many times as you'd like.

Answer (score 5):

I always use `history` it's just more convinient for me to see all the commands that I type for example:

```
history
```

lists you all commands that you typed for a while

```
history | grep nmap
```

lists you only commands with `nmap`

```
history | grep nmap | tail -10

history | grep nmap | head -10
```

lists you last and first 10 commands with `nmap`

then just copy and paste it again.

Comment: That's pretty useful, not exactly what I was looking, but thanks for sharing!

Comment: you're welcome, good luck :)

Answer (score 5):

The way that I prefer to use to achieve this is by re-maping the <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd> keys to Bash's history search. This can be achieved by adding the following to `.inputrc`:

```
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
```

After reloading your shell, pressing <kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Down</kbd> on an empty prompt will navigate through all of the commands, and pressing <kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Down</kbd> after typing e.g. `nmap` will navigate through all of the commands that started with what you typed.

Answer (score 3):

If you are in vi mode in bash (`set -o vi`), you can go in command mode (press <kbd>Esc</kbd>), and then type `/whatever_you_want`, followed by <kbd>Enter.</kbd>

It will search whatever you want, and you can scroll with `j` and `k` keys. Hit enter when you found the right command.

To be able to type commands when you have hitted Esc, you have to hit `i` (this is vi).

Going back to "normal" shell mode is done via `set -o emacs`.

Comment: This is not the required answer, every linux user knows how to use `vi ` editor, the question has nothing to do with do `vi`

Comment: @Faizan bash, and many other shells, have vi keybindings, where you can press Esc and then vi-like keys to do things.

Comment: @muru i know it, but how does it answer the question?

Comment: @Faizan Searching using `/` - an alternate to Ctrl-R given in the accepted answer.

Comment: `/` followed by `nmap` in current scenario .

Comment: I didn't know if Ryan is aware of the vi mode in the shell. If he didn't know, he is not aware of the rexp search available. If he was aware of those mode, I suppose that the emacs equivalent was known, so no question... This explains my reply.